# How would an "minecraft-like" dimension behave?

Tags: planets, physics, earth-like, alternate-worlds

[image]

The "dimension" I'm building, consists of earth-like plane that stretches on to infinity.
It's a soft sci-fi universe and this dimension is man-made.

- The land has infinite mass, I don't know what implications this would bring.
- The sun is fixed static to a point high enough, to not scorch the entire surface immediately, it never moves.
- On the picture above, the gravity would ideally stop on the black block.
- Horizontally infinite, Vertically earth-like.

This entire thing doesn't make any sense, but that's the point.  Now questions.

- How Man #1 would communicate with Man #2 on longer distances?
- Would the light get dimmer proportionally to the distance travelled away from it? **(not counting obstructions.)**
- Would this plane have a magnetic field?
- How would gravity work in this place?
- Follow up:  Would the dimension immediately collapse into a reality-destroying blackhole?

  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The gravity question has been answered here: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12442/gravity-on-a-minecraftian-world

Comment: Man, I wish I had the knowledge to actually read what that guy said and be like "Yes, I understand what you're saying.".  But, thanks anyway.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding ! Note that the light would get dimmer AND the temperature would drop. the distance would depend of the sun's distance.

Comment: I was aware of that.  If somebody happened to be teleported or launched very far off the centre, they would be left frozen in the darkness, possibly never to be seen again.

Comment: If you have a minute, please take the [tour] and have a look at the [help]. Please take special note that this is not a general discussion forum, it's more like a Q&A site. We require posts to contain **one single question** that is not so broad that entire books could be written as answers and that can have one objectively best answer. Please [edit] your post to fit these requirements. If you have several questions, ask one after the other, preferably with a day or two between them to build your world based on the answers you got.

Comment: *"How Man #1 would communicate with Man #2 on longer distances?"* When playing Minecraft with friends I use Skype.

Comment: As a comment, if the sun is fixed, then it will scorch your world. (Or be too weak to provide warmth to most if the world.) Think about how warm our sun can make a spot just in a day. This is why our planet's rotation is key to life as it gives places time to cool off before getting warmed again.